# Interesting Insert User Name Query

Tags: javascript, c#

Wanted to share a question my boss asked us at morning status meeting, a pretty interesting one one might say.

Say you have a survey on your website and an insert query for the database, how would you insert the name of the user answered the survey using

1) C#

2) Javascript

given that the user logs into the website with a password and an email. there's a different form for login page and another for index.

B.

Given that your website has an option for print\send email to client, How whould you insert the name of the user that performed the action (pressed print / send email) using

1) C#

2) Javascript.

Interesting one that made me think hard all day

Comment: Does your server run Node.js or .NET? Since normally JavaScript doesn't insert much into databases.

Comment: Being C# dev, my first tought was he is asking about difference between having insert query params or  concatenating queryfrom strings. The B point is about using some templating engine. But that's just my toughts ;)

Comment: The first thought that popped into my head was that it depends on a whole bunch of things unsaid.

Comment: it run .NET not node.js :) and that's the point, be creative think out of the box

Comment: There isn't a lot of creativity needed here, submitting a user name from a web form isn't new or ground breaking. There *is* distinct need for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly, I think your boss just needs to understand the web.

A. In C#, you'd open a database connection through a `ConnectionString`. In JavaScript, you fire an `AJAX / POST` request to let the C# back-end do this for you.

B. In C#, it would be the same as in case A. In JavaScript, you'd capture the `onclick` event for the print button. Then, once again, fire an `AJAX / POST` request to C#.

In general, JavaScript is a front-end and event-driven scripting language with functions as first class objects and prototypical inheritance. C# is your back-end language that runs on an ASP.NET IIS server.

There is a clean-cut separation of concerns with JavaScript and C#. One runs on the client / browser and the latter runs on the server.